# Assignment in if clause has no effect

Tags: c++, if-statement, variable-assignment

Consider the following code (I realize it's bad practice, just curious to see why it happens):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    bool show = false;
    int output = 3;

    if (show = output || show)
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    std::cout << "show: " << show << std::endl;

    output = 0;
    if (show = output || show)
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    std::cout << "show: " << show << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
3
show: 1
0
show: 1
```

So, apparrently in the 2nd if clause, the assignment of `output`, which is `0`, does not actually happen. If I re-write the code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    bool show = false;
    int output = 3;

    if (show = output || show)
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    std::cout << "show: " << show << std::endl;

    output = 0;
    if (show = output)  // no more || show
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    std::cout << "show: " << show << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs, as I would expect:

```
3
show: 1
show: 0
```

Can anyone explain what is actually happening here? Why is `output` not assigned to `show` in the 2nd if clause of the 1st example? Im using Visual Studio 2017 Toolchain on Windows 10.

Comment: Look up the precedence of the operators you're using.

Comment: You're doing `if (show = (output || show))`.

Comment: And this is why I assume any `if` statement containing an assignment that doesn't have the assignment properly parenthesized is **wrong**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related to operator precedence. Your code:

```
if (show = output || show)
```

is the same as

```
if (show = (output || show))
```

If you change the order, the result changes:

```
if ((show = output) || show)
```

With an if-statement like the one above, it prints:

```
3
show: 1
show: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment does not happen because operator precedence of the || operator is higher than the assignment operator. You assign output || show which is 0 ||  true which evaluates to true in the second if.